# send a camera photo to server in ionic

Tags: cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I build an application in ionic .This app use a camera plugin from Cordova to take a picture from camera and then I need to send it to server "let the server be localhost".

I write the code that open the camera and display image but i need help in sending that image to server.

this is the **controller**:

```
.controller('stuffCtrl',function($scope, Camera,$http, $cordovaFile,$cordovaFileTransfer) { 

// camera is service I built to use camera 


    //this function is called when user try to take a picture 
    $scope.getPhoto= function() {
    Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
      console.log(imageURI);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
  };

})
```

and the **camera service** :

```
angular.module('app.services')

.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        // Do any magic you need
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Huthaifah Kholi, We need to convert the image to base64 and after that we will send it to server, It is the best approch for sending image to server, but the API which you used to sending the image to server should recive the base64 and then parse it to image 
you can find plugin for converting images to base64 image :
Add this plugin in your code :

```
ionic plugin add com-badrit-base64
```

And use this code when you recived the image :

```
window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(imageFilePath, function(base64){
        console.log('file base64 encoding: ' + base64);
    });
```

Now send this base64 string to server, Or you can use it in your html pages to show the selected image.

Hope this will help you, Have a happy code day

Comment: that was a good anwer **imageURI**  contains the base64 string of the image why not send that one to server

Comment: You can send that image base64 to server and on the server side they need to convert base64 to Image on there server end.

Comment: can you give me a code ? 
I didn't understand what is base64 and how we can convert to it an send it